# Whats the best data structure/algorithm for compressing a 2D curve?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm looking to make a recursive function that reduces the data points on an amplitude/time graph, whilst preserving the features of the curve. I was initially thinking that I'd just use a loop, here in rough pseudo code;

> void compress(length time, amplitude range) {
>
> check resolution of length time isn't above resolution of data return
>   if it is;
>
> loop through length time, get min and max amplitude;
>
> if difference between min and max amplitude is within amplitude range,
>   store min and max and return;
>
> if not, divide length of time / 4 and call compress(length time/4,
>   range);

However, I realize that this would be very, very slow. The data is from matlab and there's 200k data pairs for 4 seconds of audio. Would there be a way of using a binary heap or something like that, but with two keys instead of one?

Comment: what about using standard compression methods like eg wavelets

Comment: Never heard of that before, I just looked and it seems Matlab has a wavelet toolbox. I'll give it a pop- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using line simplification approach to compress highly periodic time series like audio waves is a very bad idea. A [windowed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)/[FCT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform) compression approach would achieve much higher [PSNR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio) in this case. Basically, you partition (not precisely, because we're using window functions) the signal into small chunks of data, perform FFT/FCT on each chunk, then discard the coefficients of high frequencies. The time series of coefficients of lower frequencies can be further compressed using other conventional data compression approach, but there is generally no guarantee on its fidelity if you again use a lossy compression method.

That being said, if you still insist on using a line simplification approach from the start, [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) would be a good starting point.

Comment: thanks for this. This is for after windowed FFT. its for driving visual effects in a game engine, so preserving the shape with a few points that are all in the + axis is whats needed. A combination of the two approaches will get me the right effect...

Comment: @RobbieCooper Are you trying to implement an audio waveform visualizer or an audio frequency spectrum visualizer? Both are unrelated to data compression, and the former has much simpler algorithms (like [Envelop Detector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_detector)) depending on what you want to do.

Comment: What I need is a .csv file with two columns of comma separated data, one for time, one for amplitude/frequency, whatever I'd like to extract from the audio file. The engine is Unreal Engine 4 and it can accept .csv files to use as curves to drive visual effects...

Comment: @RobbieCooper You can use envelop detector to extract the waveform information, and windowed FFT/FCT to extract the frequency information in that case. What you do with the information is then entirely up to you.

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks. Envelope detector in matlab produces the same amount of data but its formatted better for what I need to do.